# How to fix my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

I cant seem to get my social media icons to correctly fit into the navigation bar. I have borders set up around everything so it's easier to see what is inside what. I don't understand why the social media icons are below the navigation bar. I would like for the icons to come up into the nav bar, and for all the icons to shift left inside the < div id="nav-left" >. Any help is much appreciated.

Imgur of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2wML.jpg

**My HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
         <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Website(CSS).css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
        <title>Website</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="container" id="nav-left">
                <ul class="nav-left">
                    <li id="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/#"><img src="Twitter.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Twitter" /></a></li>
                    <li id="instagram"><a href="http://instagram.com/#"><img src="Instagram.png" width="40" height="40" alt="Instagram"/></a></li>
                    <li id="quora"><a href="http://quora.com/#"><img src="Quora.jpg" width="80" height="35" alt="Quora" /></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container" id="nav-right">
                <ul class="nav-right">
                    <li id="future-plans"><a href="insert link">Future Plans</a></li>
                    <li id="contact"><a href="inset link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

**My CSS code:**

```
/* Get the whole box of social image links to be closer to the left border. 
Get the .nav-right to have better font, bigger font, and to pushed a little more to the left of the nav box. */

body {
    border: 2px solid green;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
.nav {
    height: 7%;
    width: 98%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

.nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
}



/* Left Side Navigation Container */
#nav-left {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.nav-left li  {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}



/* Right Side Navigation Container */
#nav-right {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.nav-right li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there's some extra padding on the ul (by default) that is being used for your nav links.
you need to manually null out all padding/margin for your navigator (full of social media icons) to sit nicely within another box..

You can do it specifically for your nav (without affecting anything else) by adding the two lines below

```
.nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;  // make sure there's no padding
    margin: 0px;   // and no margin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
```

it will remove all extra padding and margin of all block elements.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change display property to inline in .nav ul class and set float:left to .nav-left li class.

http://jsfiddle.net/3zc9mtnx/

```
body {
border: 2px solid green;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
.nav {
height: 7%;
width: 98%;
top: 0;
z-index: 10;
position: fixed;
background-color: white;
border: 2px solid blue;
}

.nav ul {
display: inline;
} 



/* Left Side Navigation Container */
#nav-left {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.nav-left li  {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    float:left;
}



/* Right Side Navigation Container */
#nav-right {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.nav-right li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give the style in nav-left,nav-right

```
height:auto;display:block
```